# Whats the best relational database structure for this simple contact form?

Tags: database, database-design

[image]

1- Message belongs to name, Name belongs to Email and email belongs to phone number

2- Message belongs to email, email belongs to name and name belongs to phone number

3- many messages can point to a single email and name and phone number.
Message belongs to email, message belongs to name, message belongs to phone number.

Or is there any better structure which would satisfy normalization.
The purpose of this from is to store data so that the telecaller can later contact the person who contacted via email and phone number

Comment: Hi. "Normalization" does not mean "good design". If you want to know what either of those means: Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.) PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 0):

You are not phrasing your requirements properly. So we cannot provide a precise solution.

## Entity

Instead of thinking about columns and fields, think about [entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity). What are the real-world things you are trying to track in your database and app.

If doing an appointment scheduling system for an veterinary practice, you have several entities: Customer, Animal, Doctor, MedicalAssistant, Appointment/Visit.

If your tracking employees communicating, you have Employee and Message.

## Attribute

After identifying entities, you identify [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_(computing)). What aspects of each of your entities do you care to track in your database and app? For example, your employee’s have a height and a hair color as attributes, but those two are irrelevant to your messaging app. On the other hand, each employee has conduits of communication as attributes, perhaps having an email address, an office phone, and a personal mobile phone, as examples. Again, you must ask which of those you care to track.

## Relationship & Cardinality

If you want to look up the employee's email address or phone, but track messages without regard to mode of communication, then we have two tables. The relationship is that each employee can have zero, one, or more messages, and each message must have exactly one employee. This quantifying of related rows between tables is known formally as [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Cardinalities).

In my [ASCII-art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) equivalent of [crows-feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow's_foot_notation) [ERD diagramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model):

> [employee]-1-----0-1-<[message]

As for columns on those tables:

- Current name, current email address, and current office phone number extension are all attributes (columns) on the `employee` table.
- The `message` table has a column `content`.

## Keys

The `employee` table also must have a [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) column. The primary key is usually an [*identity* column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column) (auto-incrementing sequence of integer numbers) or a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

The `message` table as wall carries a primary key column. In addition, the `message` table must have a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) column. The foreign key column contains the value of the primary key of the employee to whom the message was sent.